# Intent Service и секундомер

Tags: android, android-service

У меня есть ChronometrActivity в котором стоит Chronometr. При закрытии активити - запускается ChronometrService который должен продолжать считать секунды, а потом при возвращении на ChronometrActivity нужно брать актуальное время и устанавливать его хронометру.

Вопросы:

1. как зделать сам счетчик в моем ChronometrService(IntentService)
2. как обновить данные в ChronometrActivity,  я так полагаю, что нужно использовать BroadcastReceiver совместно с onResume, onPause  и если так, то можно пример как именно это сделать.

**UPDATE** Вопрос решен

```
Счетчик:

 private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
        mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
        mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

        sendToBroadcastReciver(mTotalMilis);

        handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // 0.1 seconds

    }
};
```

Ресивер регистрировал так

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ChronometrService.RESPONSE_RESUME_CLICK));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```